# Can i draw non living creatures with facial expressions? is it Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, cartoon

Painting is the only thing I am good at. I am so depressed when I found that painting is Haram. I want to draw non animated objects but can i draw facial expression on it like eyes and nose to make them cartoonish.

Answer (score -1):

Painting, Music, and Poetry- are the field of Art. All of them are not Categorically Haram in Islam. Syeda Aisha(S.A)- the wife of the Holy Prophet(S.A.W) played with dolls in her childhood with her friends in front of the Prophet(S.A.W). And He(S.A.W) didn't prohibit her(Sahih Bukhari-6130,Sahih Muslim 2440). So whenever you read about this thing and Ahadees on the Art. You will get both points of view.On the one hand Prophet(S.A.W) was prohibited strictly and on another hand, he didn't prohibit.
So what is the point? The point is to understand the core of it, Its essence.

First of all to say a thing Catagorricalyy Haram. It is necessary that it should be mentioned in Qura'n-the basic source of Islam. But you will not find it anywhere that the painting or Music is Haram like "Zina"-fornication is Haram in Qur'an.

Now, why is this Haram and why do scholars always demotivate it. Basically understand the origin. Due to two facts, Prophet(S.A.W) prohibited it

1. Shirk or Idolism
2. shamelessness or 'Fahashi'

when people started to paint or made some art at that time it mostly occur in that society, they move towards it.

Nowadays, after media evolves, it is a rare chance of 'Shirk' or Idolism using.But there are a lot of chances of nudity r shamelessness.

So, keeping this context in mind you can paint or do any thing in art.Just avoid
1)Shirk(Idolism)
2) Nudity
3)Wastage of time

Wallah-o-Aalam